# How can I batch update album art for my old iTunes collection in the Music.app world?

Tags: music.app, album-art

I have a very large iTunes collection from years of collecting and ripping CDs. In the past, "Get Album Artwork" usually did a decent job, but not always. If I look back about 10 years, there was an old script called 'FetchArt' which plugged into iTunes and did a great job of filling in the gaps that iTunes couldn't on its own.

I recently upgraded the library to Catalina's Music.app as iTunes seems to have been removed during the upgrade. When I first launched Music.app, it did spend quite some time going through my library and attempting to "fix" all my album art. Unfortunately, it seems to have done a horrible job at that in that all albums by a few artists that I checked seem to now have a adopted a single album cover from one album (e.g. all Iron Maiden art is now "Piece of Mind", all Peter Gabriel is "So", Red Hot Chili Peppers "Californication" has picked up a greatest hits album cover, and so on).

Is there something I missed with Music.app to make it do the right thing? Did it just mess up a good portion of my collection because of Apple's bad coding/algorithms? Is there something like the old FetchArt script that would work on Music.app or perhaps outside of the app would correct the existing files?

If it wasn't for the fact that I have about 50,000 songs in my library (yes - they're all legit believe it or not) I'd just go about it manually, so obviously I want to find a better way!